# How to find this volume using cyllindrical shells (vertical rectangles)

Tags: calculus

I want to know how to find the volume of the region OAC about the BC line using cylindrical shells with the curve given by $y^2=x^3$. I've found the volume using horizontal rectangles which gives me $$V=\int_0^82\pi(8-y)(4-x)dy=\frac{704\pi}{5}$$.

[image]

So my question is how to find this volume using cylindrical shells but with vertical rectangles instead of horizontal ones.

Comment: Take the function as $\;x(y)\;$ , i.e.: $\;x\;$ as a function of $\;y\;$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize $OAB$ in either order, to use washers or shells. Either $x$ first (outside), and $y$ second (inside), for $x$-slices:
$$\begin{align}
0&\le x\le 4\\
0&\le y\le x^{3/2}
\end{align}$$
giving vertical slices which rotate to washers
with inner radius $r=8-y_\text{max}=8-x^{3/2}$,
outer radius $R=8-y_\text{min}=8-0=8$ and thickness $dx$.
This yields
$$\begin{align}V&
=\pi\int_0^4\left(R^2-r^2\right)dx
=\pi\int_0^4\left(8^2-(8-x^{3/2})^2\right)dx\\&
=\pi\int_0^4\left(16x^{3/2}-x^3\right)dx
=\pi\left[\tfrac{32}5x^{5/2}-\tfrac14x^4\right]_0^4
=\frac{704}5\pi.
\end{align}$$
Or $y$ first (outside), and $x$ second (inside), for $y$-slices:
$$\begin{align}
0&\le y\le 8\\
y^{2/3}&\le x\le 4
\end{align}$$
giving horizontal slices which rotate to shells
with radius $r=8-y$,
height $h=x_\text{max}-x_\text{min}=4-y^{2/3}$
and thickness $dx$.
This yields
$$\begin{align}V&
=2\pi\int_0^8r\,h\,dy
=2\pi\int_0^8(8-y)\left(4-y^{2/3}\right)dy\\&
=2\pi\int_0^8\left(y^{5/3}-4y-8y^{2/3}+32\right)dy\\&
=2\pi\left[\tfrac38y^{8/3}-2y^2-\tfrac{24}5y^{5/3}+32y\right]_0^8\\&
=2\pi\left[\tfrac38\cdot256-2\cdot64-\tfrac{24}5\cdot32+32\cdot8\right]\\&
=\frac{704}5\pi.
\end{align}$$
Here's the moral of the story: The variable $t$ of the first, outer limit in the integral (or region description/parametrization) gives you either vertical **$x$-slices** (if $t=x$) or horizontal **$y$-slices** (if $t=y$). Then:

- If these slices are **parallel** to the axis of rotation, you get cylindrical **shells** for volume elements $dV=2\pi rh\,dt$ (with outer variable $t=x$ or $y$) with a height $h$ determined by the upper and lower limits of the inner variable (as a function of the outer), and a radius $r$ determined by the distance of the outer variable to the parallel axis of rotation.
- If the slices are **perpendicular** to the axis of rotation, you get **washers** ($R>r>0$) or disks ($R>r=0$) for volume elements $dV=\pi(R^2-r^2)dt$ with outer & inner radii $R$ & $r$ determined by the maximum and minimum distances from the axis of rotation to the upper and lower bounds for the inner variable, as functions of the outer variable.

So you did cylindrical shells; I did washers first, then shells. You can't do this with vertical area elements and the shell formula; you need the washer formula because when you rotate vertical area elements (infinitesimally thin rectangles) around a horizontal line, you get washers (a big thin disk minus a small thin disk), because the slices are perpendicular to the axis of rotation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question, the difference of shells and washers is because one is parallel to the axis of rotation and another is perpendicular to the axis of rotation?

Comment: Yes. Rotate a line segment like $x\in[1,2],y\in\{1\}$ about the $x$- and $y$-axes: in the first case, the segment is parallel and so you get a cylinder. In the second, it's perpendicular so you get a washer. Just draw a sketch to convince yourself.